# Using a rails model in Capybara tests

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

I set up a project where all I have to do is display a set of records from an SQLlite3 database. I have a table in that database, and I want the root page to display all the records in the database. I have this working, but now I want to set up a Capybara test to make sure that the page has the first and last record from the table on the page.

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe "seeing record from scotlands model " do
  specify "I can see a list of all charities" do
    visit "/"
    expect(page).to have_content "@table.first_record"
  end
end
```

However, the above provides no link to the model so I cannot access it. How do I get a link to the table from the test file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you generally try to access real data from tests? I've always learned to keep those things separate.

I like to work with Rspec and Capybara. Here is something simple and straight forward that should accomplish what you've discussed:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "user sees all scotlands records" do

  scenario "successfully" do

    charity1 = Charity.create(name: name1, info: info1)
    charity2 = Charity.create(name: name2, info: info2)
    charity3 = Charity.create(name: name3, info: info3)

    visit root_path

    expect(page).to have_content(charity1.name)
    expect(page).to have_content(charity1.info)

    expect(page).to have_content(charity2.name)
    expect(page).to have_content(charity2.info)

    expect(page).to have_content(charity3.name)
    expect(page).to have_content(charity3.info)

  end

end
```

I actually usually work with FactoryGirl also. In this case it'd make things easier because you could use `create_list` and make as many records as you'd like with just one line of code.

Comment: I was going to use the actual data but it seems to not be the correct way of doing it. The FactoryGirl suggestion sounds good, I will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, normally Rails will not touch the real db from the test environment.